# Disable automatic Google consent revocation link show

Tags: cookies

is possible to disable auto show floating bar (on image). Which is automaticly showed after scroll down on my website, which has implemented Google AdSense and enabled GDPR message.

Thank you, very much for help

[Image of bar which I need remove - Google cookie consent mesaage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHAYg.png)

I Googled this, but without sucess